# django-import-export : getting post_export to update models

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

Please how do i updated exported Company model below using post_export signal.
I don't want to export items not exported before. So the best thing is using signals.

However, if i print the model in the signal at the end of the code below, I get a type class e.g `<class 'app.models.Company'>`

I know am doing something wrong by saving a model but can't find my way arround.

Maybe I'm not understanding the documentation of `django-import-export` library which is found [here](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#signals).

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Companies"

    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    imported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    exported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.company_name:
            return self.company_name
        return self.domain
```

admin.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver 
from import_export.signals import post_import, post_export

class CompanyResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('website', 'user', 'country', 'source', 'industry')

@admin.register(Company)
class CompanyAmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = CompanyResource
    list_display = ('domain', 'website', 'exported', 'added_on')
    list_filter = ('user', 'country', 'imported', 'exported', 'added_on')


@receiver(post_export, dispatch_uid='ss1')
def _post_export(model, **kwargs):
    print(model) 
    model.exported = True
    model.save() # This line when included raises Error: "save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" so code breaks here
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions

> Notice that the function takes a sender argument, along with wildcard
>   keyword arguments (**kwargs); all signal handlers must take these
>   arguments.

```
@receiver(post_export, dispatch_uid='ss1')
def _post_export(sender, model, **kwargs):
    model.exported = True
    model.save()
```

UPDATED:
django-import-export don't send exported queryset in signal

so u can override export_action in ModelAdmin

```
@admin.register(Company)
class CompanyAmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = CompanyResource
    list_display = ('domain', 'website', 'exported', 'added_on')
    list_filter = ('user', 'country', 'imported', 'exported', 'added_on')

    def export_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().export_action(request, *args, **kwargs)
        qs = self.get_export_queryset(request)
        qs.update(exported=True)
        return response
```

Comment: The django-import-export doesn't specify this from the documentation. Also in the source code which i checked sender is None

Comment: just ignore sender

Answer (score 1):

Арсений Краснов solution has a problem, updated the model before exporting it not after.

To export after, you must add the following function in your resources.ModelResource

```
class CompanyResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('website', 'user', 'country', 'source', 'industry')

    def after_export(self, queryset, data, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset.update(exported=True)
```